# IllegalArgumentException locking surface

Tags: java, android

**Device Samsung galaxy s3. OS-4.0.4.I have a list view diplaying list items.Then after i keep my phone idle for 5-10 min,agian when i unlock and resume my application i see this exception**

```
E/SurfaceTextureClient( 9044): dequeueBuffer failed (No such device)
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044): IllegalArgumentException locking surface
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044): at android.view.Surface.lockCanvasNative(Native Method)
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):        at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:76)
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2157)
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1846)
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2658)
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
E/ViewRootImpl( 9044):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: code flow is complex.im sure no mistake in code.its just adding items,nothing complex in that returning view.Even it works fine in all the phones.only in galaxy s3, when i add items continusly approx 10-15, i get this exception.

Comment: I am seeing a similar crash in my app.  See my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838529/dequeuebuffer-exception), as well as similar questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23370836/illegalargumentexception-surface-nativelockcanvas-choreographer-bufferqueue) and (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254292/could-not-lock-surface).  So this is not localized.