# IllegalArgumentException Surface.nativeLockCanvas , Choreographer, BufferQueue

Tags: java, android, illegalargumentexception, glsurfaceview

I have a complex application that creates multiple Bitmap objets and uses them to create BitmapDrawables. I know this might be a tough question to answer, but any help in pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated. I have run tests on memory allocation, and have come up mostly empty handed. ... Any ideas on what could be causing this?

LOG:

```
04-29 12:48:00.442: E/BufferQueue(177): [com.example.app/com.example.app.Activity_One] queueBuffer: fence is NULL
04-29 12:48:00.442: E/Surface(2154): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-29 12:48:00.442: W/Adreno-EGLSUB(2154): <SwapBuffers:1374>: failed to queueBuffer
04-29 12:48:00.442: W/Adreno-EGL(2154): <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3654>: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
04-29 12:48:04.486: W/Adreno-EGLSUB(2154): <DequeueBuffer:606>: dequeue native buffer fail: Unknown error 2147483646, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
04-29 12:48:04.486: E/BufferQueue(177): [com.example.app/com.example.app.Activity_One] dequeueBuffer: can't dequeue multiple buffers without setting the buffer count
04-29 12:48:04.486: W/Adreno-EGLSUB(2154): <DequeueBuffer:606>: dequeue native buffer fail: Invalid argument, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
04-29 12:48:04.486: W/Adreno-ES20(2154): <gl2_surface_swap:43>: GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY
04-29 12:48:04.486: W/Adreno-EGL(2154): <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3597>: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
04-29 12:48:04.486: W/HardwareRenderer(2154): EGL error: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
04-29 12:48:04.506: W/HardwareRenderer(2154): Mountain View, we've had a problem here. Switching back to software rendering.
04-29 12:48:08.440: E/Surface(2154): dequeueBuffer failed (Unknown error 2147483646)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154): Could not lock surface
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:243)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2435)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2409)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2253)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1883)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-29 12:48:08.480: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 12:48:09.441: E/BufferQueue(177): [com.example.app/com.example.app.Activity_One] dequeueBuffer: can't dequeue multiple buffers without setting the buffer count
04-29 12:48:09.441: E/Surface(2154): dequeueBuffer failed (Invalid argument)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154): Could not lock surface
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:243)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2435)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2409)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2253)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1883)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-29 12:48:09.461: E/ViewRootImpl(2154):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 12:48:09.761: E/BufferQueue(177): [com.example.app/com.example.app.Activity_One] dequeueBuffer: can't dequeue multiple buffers without setting the buffer count
…
```

Comment: You're not running out of memory.  The failure is in the first couple of log lines -- the BufferQueue is getting in a bad state, rejecting attempts to queue a buffer.  So the buffer is still officially "checked out", and when lockCanvas() tries to dequeue another one the BufferQueue is saying no.  It looks like the root cause is a NULL fence being passed to queueBuffer().  Not sure what would cause that.

Comment: Thanks @fadden ... [Here's](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/708cc79/libs/gui/BufferQueue.cpp) where the null fence might be, I'm still working on hunting this down.

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with the device or version of Android I am using. I switched devices and android versions, and haven't been able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: That is certainly possible.  What device / version shows the problem?

Comment: @fadden, it's a Asus Nexus 7, running Android 4.4.2., Kit-Kat

Comment: I'm having the same issue, also N7 (2013) Android 4.4.2.  User interface is not anything special.

Comment: Interesting, I am also having a similar issue on an Android 4.4.2 device (Asus Nexus 7).  It happens roughly (or maybe exactly) 5 minutes after I launch the app.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error. For me the problem was that I was not closing the file (file.close()) in JNI code.

Comment: What are u doing with the file in JNI ? Since, I am getting the same exception while using Jni code