# android Could not lock surface : dequeueBuffer failed (Unknown error 2147483646)

Tags: android

I am getting this error while navigating through my app.It happens every 5-10 transitions and restarts the app.

here is the exception i got while app crashes.

Please help me to solve the issue.

```
12-22 16:33:41.625: E/Surface(23199): dequeueBuffer failed (Unknown error 2147483646)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199): Could not lock surface
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:243)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2461)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2435)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2279)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1909)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-22 16:33:41.633: E/ViewRootImpl(23199):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I googled it and came to some of the solutions but they are all about webview.I didn't used webview or SurfaceView in my app.
I have also tried "android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in manifest file but issue still persist.

Comment: You are passing an invalid argument somewhere. Can you share the relevant part of the code?

Comment: actually it happens in almost every activity.And there are only two operations i am doing in each and every activity.First is "Loading bitmap using picasso from SD card " and Second is "database operations".Will anything from this cause this issue? It might be picasso but not sure and don't know why it behaves like this.?

Comment: You must look at the arguments of the functions you are calling. Somewhere you pass an invalid argument and that causes the issue. Look here: Surface.java:243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was Picasso causing this issue.I was allocating a new object of picasso.Using a Singleton Object of picasso solves the issue.

Comment: oh gosh!! Thank you! it took me so long to figure out that this is the issue

Comment: What about in Glide?